# Filtering array of objects and nested objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
  var data = [
  {
    type: "parent",
    children: [
      {
        type: "parent",
        children: [
            {
              type: "parent"
            },
            {
              type: "parent",
              children: [
                {
                 type: "notParent"
                },
                {
                 type: "parent"
                }
              ]
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: "parent",
    children: [
      {
        type: "parent"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: "parent",
    children: [
      {
        type: "parent",
        children: [
          {
            type: "parent"
          },
          {
            type: "parent"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        type: "notParent"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: "notParent"
  }
]
```

This data is an array of objects, and can have objects deeply nested. What I want to do is to create a new array that only contains the objects with the type: "parent" and remove all others. I am finding it hard to make this work for deeply nested objects. I have tried many variations of the following:

```
        var findAllParents = function(obj, type) {
            if(obj.type === type) { return obj; }
            for(var i in obj) {
                if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                    var foundParents = findAllParents(obj[i], type);
                    if(foundParents) { return foundParents; }
                }
            }
            return null;
        };
```

I would like for this to return data like this:

```
  var data = [
  {
    type: "parent",
    children: [
      {
        type: "parent",
        children: [
            {
              type: "parent"
            },
            {
              type: "parent",
              children: [
                {
                 type: "parent"
                }
              ]
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: "parent",
    children: [
      {
        type: "parent"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: "parent",
    children: [
      {
        type: "parent",
        children: [
          {
            type: "parent"
          },
          {
            type: "parent"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Only to return all objects with type: "parent"

Comment: You want it to 1D array of still nested. Please add expected output.

Comment: Any error(s) when you execute this code?

Comment: @MaheerAli I have updated with expected output

Comment: @Variable no errors, just the wrong output - https://repl.it/repls/RoastedSolidFlash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
    {
        type: "parent",
        children: [
            {
                type: "parent",
                children: [
                    {
                        type: "parent"
                    },
                    {
                        type: "parent",
                        children: [
                            {
                                type: "notParent",
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        type: "parent"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                type: "parent"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: "parent",
        children: [
            {
                type: "parent"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: "parent",
        children: [
            {
                type: "parent",
                children: [
                    {
                        type: "parent",
                        children: [
                            {
                                type: "parent",
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        type: "notParent"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        type: "parent"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                type: "notParent"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: "notParent"
    }
];

const filterCollectionItemsOfType = (collection, expectedType = 'parent') => {
    const filteredCollection = collection.filter((item) => item.type === expectedType);

    filteredCollection.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.children && item.children.length) {
            item.children = filterCollectionItemsOfType(item.children, expectedType);
        }
    });

    return filteredCollection;
}

const parentsCollection = filterCollectionItemsOfType(data);

console.log(parentsCollection);
```

Comment: I've corrected the snippet, could you try your scenarios again?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering if there is a way to expand your answer to work for data that is even more nested https://repl.it/repls/NaturalRewardingBusinesssoftware

Comment: You can remove the type check and just check if (item.children) the call the recursion again, the type check would be useful only if you want to get the children of a specific type

Comment: Could you help me to figure out the difference between the output and the expected output ? Far as I see it works with the data from repl.it/repls/NaturalRewardingBusinesssoftware

Comment: I updated the data in https://repl.it/repls/NaturalRewardingBusinesssoftware 
the code doesn't work for objects deeply nested

Comment: Could you check the snippet again please.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of the `data` and then apply the recursive function which will remove the desired elements from the `children` array of each object using `filter()`

```js
var data = [ { type: "parent", children: [ { type: "parent", children: [ { type: "parent" }, { type: "parent" } ] } ] }, { type: "parent", children: [ { type: "parent" } ] }, { type: "parent", children: [ { type: "parent", children: [ { type: "parent" }, { type: "parent" } ] }, { type: "notParent" } ] } ]

function remove(obj){
  if(obj.children){
    obj.children = obj.children.filter(x => x.type === "parent");
    obj.children.forEach(x => remove(x))
  }
}

let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

copy.forEach(x => remove(x));

console.log(copy)
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering! Im so sorry, I should have given a better example, I have updated my question with a more accurate example of the data I need to modify. Some of the objects I need to check will be further nested, and some of them will be at the top level, so obj.children.filter won't work